# Script works from 3d view but not from Shape Keys (properties) window

Tags: python

I wrote a simple script for faster working with shape keys on multiple objects, and it works when it’s called from 3d View window, but from object Properties window (where it most fast way to call and use) - it works only for a single object, not for all which selected…
I think it’s because of some context nuances, but can’t find the correct solution, please help!

```
import bpy

class MultiShapeKeySwitcher(bpy.types.Operator):
    """On-Off selected (active) shape key on multiple objects."""
    bl_idname = "mesh.multishapekeyswitcher"
    bl_label = "MultiShapeKeySwitcher"


    def execute(self, context):
        
        #Script start: 

        currentactiveobject = bpy.context.active_object
        skn = bpy.context.active_object.active_shape_key.name
        skm = bpy.context.active_object.active_shape_key.mute
        
        for o in bpy.context.selected_objects:
            
            bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = bpy.data.objects[o.name]
            bpy.context.object.data.shape_keys.key_blocks[skn].mute = not skm
            #making this shape key active (selected):
            sk_index = bpy.context.object.data.shape_keys.key_blocks.find(skn)
            bpy.context.object.active_shape_key_index = sk_index
            

        #bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = currentactiveobject
        
        #Script end.
        
        return {'FINISHED'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(MultiShapeKeySwitcher)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MultiShapeKeySwitcher)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Try using the passed `context` instead of `bpy.context`

Comment: thanks for the reply! looks like this doesn't help, same behaviour, if I understand you right.
(in the beginning, I assign pc = bpy.context and replace all bpy.context with pc)

Comment: Goal is to set the mute state for all objects in selection based on the active key? If so, no need to change the active key or object -> https://pasteall.org/coJ0/raw. As mentioned by Gorgious, replace all occurrences of `bpy.context.*` with `context.*` since it is already passed to the method -> `execute(self, context)`, see my demo. Run the script, select the key, all relevant objects and press the button.

Comment: Hi @brockmann thanks for the answer, but I can't achieve your example to work.. when I press the button - nothing happened, shape keys isn't switching (mute/unmute)... What's can be wrong?) As well I'm tried to replace bpy.context.* with context.* and this gives me an error...